# Cannot authenticate with emberfire

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, firebase

I am currently following this tutorial to authenticate my EmberApp with Firebase: [Ember authentication with Firebase](http://vikram-s-narayan.github.io/blog/authentication-with-ember-and-firebase-part-1/). I am working on the part which uses the Torii addon for authentication.

Here is what I have done so far:

*app/torii-adapters/application.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ToriiFirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/torii-adapters/firebase';

export default ToriiFirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

*app/adapters/application.js*

```
import config from '../../config/environment';
import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firebase';
import Firebase from 'firebase';

export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: new Firebase(config.firebase)
});
```

*config/environment.js*

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'my-auth-test',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    firebase: 'MY_FIREBASE_URL',
    torii: {
      sessionServiceName: 'session'
    },
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary             build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };
...
```

*routes/application.js -> Login function*

```
login: function() {
  var controller = this.get('controller');
  var email = controller.get('userEmail');
  var password = controller.get('userPassword');
  this.get('session').open('firebase', {
    provider: 'password',
    email: email,
    password: password
  }).then(function() {
    this.transitionTo('protected');
  }.bind(this));
}
```

The problem that I have is the following error:
Please set the `firebase` property in your environment config.

But as far as I can see I have the property set. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

That's the old method.  Recently I ran into a similar issue after copy/pasting my old implementation, but after a quick look at https://github.com/firebase/emberfire I updated my `config/environment.js` to the following and was able to get it to work.

Try:

```
// config/environment.js
var ENV = {
  firebase: {
    apiKey: 'xyz',
    authDomain: 'YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: 'YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.appspot.com',
  }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Why does it solve the problem? What was the poster doing incorrectly?